# Swift optional property using KVC causes crash

Tags: swift, option-type, kvc

I found that using KVC in Swift causes many problems, especially with optional properties.

Here is my specific problem:

Here is a Class named **Person**. It has a normal property called **age**,and a Optional(Int) property called **ageOptional**.

```
class Person: NSObject {

    var age: Int

    var ageOptional: Int?


    override init(age: Int){

        self.age = 0
    }
}
```

Now, I use KVC in Person's instance:

```
//new a instance
var person = Person()

//kvc for normal property: it work well
person.setValue(28, forKeyPath: "age")


//but, this time ,it doesn't work well!!!!
person.setValue(28, forKeyPath: "ageOptional")
```

The app crashes, and here is the exception:

> 2015-07-11 11:17:31.546 CFRuntime[4646:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
>       this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ageOptional.'

I found that, if a property is optional, KVC couldn't find the key. But,I can't find the useful key for an optional property ,and resolve this situation.

Comment: Remove the Chinese chars, it's really not necessary, English is what people use here. And there is really no need for the multiple `！`  characters. Clear & well-formated questions would get answers.

Comment: [<CFRuntime.Person 0x7905e720> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Answer (score 2):

You have already solved the problem perfectly. You cannot use KVC on an Optional Int property, because KVC is Cocoa / Objective-C, and Objective-C cannot see an Optional Int - it is not bridged to Objective-C. Objective-C can only see types that are *bridged* to Objective-C:

- class types that are derived from NSObject
- class types that are exposed with `@objc`
- Swift structs that are bridged

Objective-C can also see an Optional wrapping any of those types - almost. It can see an Optional wrapping a bridged struct, but only if that struct is directly bridged. Int is *not* directly bridged; it is bridged to NSNumber, but not directly (it has to be wrapped). Thus, Objective-C cannot see a Swift member typed as an `Int?`.

If you really need this to be an Optional, and if you really need to use KVC on it, then declare it as `NSNumber?`, not `Int?`. Personally, I would doubt whether either of those things is true; since converting all my apps from Objective-C to Swift, I've found that I don't actually need KVC internally, and that all my KVC-based solutions can be done some other, better way.

Comment: Oh No, But, I test a String Optional Property and Use KVC again, it's work well.......

    class Person: NSObject {

        var name: String?
    }


then

Comment: Oh No, But, I test a String Optional Property and Use KVC again, it's work well.......

        var name: String?

        var person = Person()

        person.setValue("张三", forKeyPath: "name")

Comment: But not `Int?`. If you really need this to be an Optional, use `NSNumber?`.

Comment: you can override [setValue:forUndefinedKey:] and handle the optional support yourself.

Comment: you can also add `@objc` to your properties that are not recognized and it will bridge to objective c