# Adding one read only attribute to Core Data Model in Swift. Which doesn't exist in XCDataModel

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Adding attribute to entity which don't exist in XCDataModel was easily accomplised VIA @synthesize and @dynamic in objective c.
Please guide how to achieve this in swift.

```
@NSManaged public var salesPrice: NSNumber?
public var totalVal: NSNumber {
   get {
       return salesPrice ?? NSNumber(value: 0)
   }
}
```

Here sales price is managed but totalVal is not managed nor exist in xcDataModel. I am getting crash 'The entity is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'totalVal' on accessing totalVal.

```
if let coreObj = indItem.parentObj.value(forKey: keyPath) { }
```

Crash happening here.

- 'indItem.parentObj' this is right object (I double checked)
- 'keyPath' is 'totalVal' (I copied it rightly)

Comment: Please show the code where you are accessing `totalVal`, there is no problem with the code you have currently shown. It sounds like you're accessing totalVal using something like a sort descriptor or other key-value coding accessor

Comment: Thanks for your time. I updated question. Crashing code is present in question.

Comment: I assume you have to use `value(forKey:)` because you don't know the property you're looking for at runtime? So you can't just do `parentObj.totalVal`?

Comment: Can't you do `indItem.parentObj.totalVal `?

Comment: See [Swift optional property using KVC causes crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31353182)

Comment: @Willeke, as jrturton mentioned. Property will be decided at runtime. So direct attribute can't be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support key-value coding for a type declared in Swift, you have to mark it with the `@objc` keyword:

```
@objc public var totalVal: NSNumber {
```

Comment: thanks for saving my time.